# Wrap a div dynamically using jQuery depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a bootstrap carousel. Here if window width i more than 400px, I need to show all inner `div`s in same item. But if the window width is less than 400px, I need to show every 3 inner `div`s in 
one `<div class="item">`. I have this code:

```js
function item_wrap() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  console.log(width);
  if (width > 400) {
    $('.inner').unwrap();
    $('.inner').wrapAll('<div class="item active">');
  } else {

    $('.inner').unwrap();
    $('.inner:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="item active">');
    $('.inner:gt(2)').wrapAll('<div class="item">');
  }

}

item_wrap();

$(window).resize(function() {
  item_wrap();

});
```

```css
.item {
  background: #ccc;
}
.active {
  color: red
}
.inner {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 300px) {
  .inner {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div>
          <div class="inner">1</div>
          <div class="inner">2</div>
          <div class="inner">3</div>
          <div class="inner">4</div>
          <div class="inner">5</div>
          <div class="inner">6</div>
          <div class="inner">7</div>
          <div class="inner">8</div>
          <div class="inner">9</div>
          <div class="inner">10</div>
          <div class="inner">11</div>
          <div class="inner">12</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control left-carousel" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" style="display:block"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control right-carousel" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" style="background: inherit !important;display: block;height: auto;opacity: 0.5;right: -4%;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

    </div>








  </div>
</div>
```

If window width is greater than 400px it is working correctly. But if the window width is less than 400px the first 3 inner divs are showing correct
    but other inner div are not correctly wrappped in `<div class="item">`

> what i need is if in window width less than 400px then first 3 inner
>   div is need wrap in `<div class="item active">` and all other ecah 3
>   inner div is need to wrap in `<div class="item">`.

ie , if window width less than 400px i need to get the following structure

```
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
              <div>
              <div class="item-active">    
                <div class="inner">1</div>
                <div class="inner">2</div>
                <div class="inner">3</div>
               </div>  
               <div class="item">   
                <div class="inner">4</div>
                <div class="inner">5</div>
                <div class="inner">6</div>
               </div>
               <div class="item">   
                <div class="inner">7</div>
                <div class="inner">8</div>
                <div class="inner">9</div>
               </div>
               <div class="item">   
                <div class="inner">10</div>
                <div class="inner">11</div>
                <div class="inner">12</div>
               </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
```

Please help to solve this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function item_wrap(){
    var width = $(window).width();
console.log(width);
if(width > 400) {
 $('.inner').unwrap();
 $('.inner').wrapAll('<div class="item active">');
} else {

 $('.inner').unwrap();
        var divs = $(".inner");
        for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
            if(i===0){
                $('.inner:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="item active">');
            }
            else{
               divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='item'></div>"); 
            }

        }


}

}

  item_wrap();

   $(window).resize(function(){
item_wrap();

});



   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Idea**

Here's the code that works. The idea is that you loop through the remaining items after the first three, taking three items at a time, and wrap them into the div. Then take the next three and wrap them again, and so forth.

**Main code:**

```
    for (var i = 0; i < others.length; i += 3) {
        var nextThree = [others[i], others[i+1], others[i+2]]'
        $(nextThree).wrapAll('<div class="item">');
    }
```

**Full code:**

```js
function item_wrap() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  console.log(width);
  if (width > 400) {
    $('.inner').unwrap();
    $('.inner').wrapAll('<div class="item active">');
  } else {

    $('.inner').unwrap();
    var firstThree = $('.inner:lt(3)');
    var others = $('.inner:gt(2)');
    $(firstThree).wrapAll('<div class="item active">');

    for (var i = 0; i < others.length; i += 3) {
        var nextThree = [others[i], others[i+1], others[i+2]]'
        $(nextThree).wrapAll('<div class="item">');
    }
    
  }

}

item_wrap();

$(window).resize(function() {
  item_wrap();

});
```

```css
.item {
  background: #ccc;
}
.active {
  color: red
}
.inner {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) and (min-width: 300px) {
  .inner {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">


    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div>
          <div class="inner">1</div>
          <div class="inner">2</div>
          <div class="inner">3</div>
          <div class="inner">4</div>
          <div class="inner">5</div>
          <div class="inner">6</div>
          <div class="inner">7</div>
          <div class="inner">8</div>
          <div class="inner">9</div>
          <div class="inner">10</div>
          <div class="inner">11</div>
          <div class="inner">12</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control left-carousel" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true" style="display:block"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control right-carousel" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next" style="background: inherit !important;display: block;height: auto;opacity: 0.5;right: -4%;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

    </div>








  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please check this again. Why there is error ?